# Automapper - map properties to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I am creating an Web API with .NetCore and EntityFramework Core.
I have an object based on this model:

```
 public partial class Person
{
    public int Person_Id { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And i have a resource like this:

```
public string Property { get; set; }

public string V1 { get; set; }

public string V2 { get; set; }
```

I would like to use the Automapper in order to map each property of the model (Person_Id, Nickname, City) to an IEnumerable of the resource, so that i achieve something like this:

```
[
 {
  Property: Person_Id,
  V1: null,
  V2: null
 },
 {
  Property: Nickname,
  V1: null,
  V2: null
 },
 {
  Property: City,
  V1: null,
  V2: null
 }
]
```

So each property becomes a new entry in the IEnumerable.
How do i do this?

Comment: docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: Could you specify what's comming from DB (Entities) and what's your wished model?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I don't get how this helps me here, sorry

Comment: @juagicre the DB delivers a person (i.e. Person_Id: 1, Nickname: "John", City: "New York") and i want an `IEnumerable<Resource>` (i.e. `[
 {
  Property: Person_Id,
  V1: "1",
  V2: null
 },
 {
  Property: Nickname,
  V1: "John",
  V2: null
 },
 {
  Property: City,
  V1: "New York",
  V2: null
 }
]`

Comment: Are you using EF to get the DB data or do you get it via API in json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of logic is very custom and I don't think Automapper can handle it, simply because it is not 1:1 mapping but 1:3 (or even more if you want to have more properties on your `Person` class). So i suggest you do it with Reflection, instead of wasting time to do it with Automapper. Don't get me wrong - Automapper is the best there is for 1:1 mapping, but I've never seen it used for such scenario. Just go custom logic:

```
public partial class Person
    {
        public int Person_Id { get; set; }
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Resource
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public string V1 { get; set; }
        public string V2 { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var item = new Person()
            {
                Person_Id = 1,
                City = "New York",
                Nickname = "John"
            };

            PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            List<Resource> result = new List<Resource>();

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                result.Add(new Resource()
                {
                    Property = prop.Name,
                    V1 = prop.GetValue(item).ToString(),
                    V2 = null
                });
            }

            // result is now [ { Property: Person_Id, V1: "1", V2: null }, { Property: Nickname, V1: "John", V2: null }, { Property: City, V1: "New York", V2: null } ]
        }
    }
```

Of course you can speed up the process by not traversing the properties, but just hardcoding the property names using `nameof(Person.Person_Id)` and so on